# Factor this trinomial of the form : ax2 + bx + c specifically : 7m2 - 23m + 6

Tags: functions

My Baldor Algebra book (2000) , on page 163 , gives examples of trinomials  of the form
ax2 + bx + c and includes 7m2 - 23m + 6 (but does not provide the answer for this example)
If the question had been to factor 7m2 -13m + 6 = (7m - 6 )( m - 1)
Does my question : Factor 7m2 - 23m + 6 have a real answer ? What is the answer ?
How can I prove that there is no real answer to this Factoring Question ?

Comment: `Factor@(6 - 23 m + 7 m^2)` gives `(-3 + m) (-2 + 7 m)` and `Factor@(6 - 13 m + 7 m^2)` gives `(-1 + m) (-6 + 7 m)`.

Comment: How I arrived at the answer? I didn't, Mathematica did using the `Factor` command when provided with the correct syntax. Please comment under your post and delete your answer. Also note the syntax for squaring an expression. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCFhf.png) is how Mathematica solved it. You can set up a free [cloud account](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) or get acquainted with the AI-enabled natural language friendly engine called [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Otherwise, this community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (checklist): 
❌: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: Are you asking for a technique to factor $7m^2 - 23m + 6$?  Please clarify your question.  Please explain what you have attempted, where you are stuck, and your mathematics background.   This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).